# Prove that $\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0}\frac{3n^2+2} {n \cdot (5n-1)^2}$ is convergent

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that $\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0}\frac{3n^2+2} {n \cdot (5n-1)^2}$ is convergent? I failed doing it with the comparison test and root test aswell as fraction test seem far too complicated to me. Is there an easy way?

Comment: Is this convergence of a sequence? If so, divide the top and bottom by $n^3$, and note that $\frac 1n$ goes to zero as $n$ increases.

Answer (score 0):

Fill in details:

$$\frac{3n^2+2}{n(5n-1)^2}\ge\frac{3n^2}{n\cdot25n^2}=\frac3{25}\cdot\frac1{n}$$

Comment: to conclude that the series diverges, right?

Comment: Ohh okay I see. Thank you so it doesn't even converge... That's why I am not able to prove it.

Comment: @RSerrao Yes, of course...

Comment: @user405981 Indeed. But also pay attention to the fact that you should at least remark the series is a positive one so you can use the comparison test at all...

Answer (score 0):

Using the Comparison Ratio Test:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\frac{3n^2+2} {n  (5n-1)^2}:\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{3}{25}\ne 0\Rightarrow\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{3n^2+2} {n  (5n-1)^2}\sim \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1} {n}\text{ (divergent).}$$

Answer (score -1):

See [Limit Comparison Test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesCompTest.aspx). As $a_n$ is of order $1/n$ the series will diverge.

[image]

Comment: I was talking about a series sorry. Edited the post.

Comment: Then the series will not converge as it is of order $1/n$

Comment: @Sachidanand Prasad  And how can I prove that?

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: Why downvote is given?